# Is Distributed Lag and Moving Average the same thing?

Tags: time-series, moving-average, ardl

I am currently reading Principle of Econometrics by Hill, Griffith and Lim, in the part on time series, they use the term Distributed Lag (DL) , and ARDL(1,1) etc.

So is DL the same thing as Moving average used by most other text?

Comment: My guess is that ARDL(p, q) is $y_t=\sum_{j=1}^p\beta_jy_{t-j}+\sum_{i=0}^q\theta_ix_{t-i}+\epsilon_t$ with p and q possibly swapped, but really this should be clear from the textbook. Do you know what a moving average model looks like?